# Number generating C++

Tags: c++, visual-c++

In your homework 1, you will write a program to generate the grades of all the students in your class, 
and calculate the distributions. Assume the following:

(1) The number of the students in your class is a random number between [131, 162].
(2) Every student's grade  is a random integer between [10, 100].
(3) If the grade is in [10, 59], the letter grade is F; If the grade is in [60, 74], the letter grade is C; 
    If the grade is in [75, 84], the letter grade is B; If the grade is in [85, 100], the letter grade is A.
(4) You should calculate the highest grade (point grade, not letter grade) and lowest grade (point grade).
(4) For your final output, please print the following:
    -- There are *** students in my class!
    <-- A's
      B's**
        C's 
        **F's 
    -- The highest grade is** !
    -- The lowest grade is **!

Please note that you need to substitute these ***'s with numbers you generated from your program.  A screenshot of a sample output could be found in the attachment; notice that numbers in it are just randomly generated.

I am having a hard time with the first part of this homework in which u have to generate # of students between the range specified.

This is what I am doing

```
    int randomN;
randomN = rand()% 31+131;
```

it gives me one number obviously. What I am having trouble implementing is that number into an array ranging from 1 to the random number that comes out. I've used MATLAB before and in there you would do something like x = 1:randomN and it will generate an array. How do I do this on C++? and if you have to use loops, could u please give me hints on that? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a function that generates a random number in a given range.You can find many on the net, although you seem to almost have it:

```
//return random number from min to max, 
//but not including max, i.e in range [min,max)
int randN(const int min, const int max)
{ 
  return rand() % (max-min)+min; 
}
```

There are some issue with above in terms of randomness, but its not a big problem for this project. Now you can call that function like so:

```
//generate random number from 10 to 100
const int randomGrade = randN(10,101); 
const int randomNumberOfStudents = randN(131,163);
```

Answer (score 0):

Come up with a pseudocode algorithm:

1. Calculate the number of students, `N`, between 131-162
2. Allocate an array, `A`, of size `N`
3. For i=0-(N-1), generate a grade, `g`, between 10-100
4. Set `A[i] = g;`

Or in code:

```
//assumes that you have a helper method `myRandomGen` that takes 
//a min and max value
int numberOfStudents = myRandomGen(131,162);
int* grades = new int[numberOfStudents];
for(int i = 0; i < numberOfStudents; ++i) {
   grades[i] = myRandomGen(10,100);
}


// do something with the array, then free up the memory
delete[] grades;
```

Answer (score -1):

```
int randomN = rand() % 32 + 131;
std::vector<int> grades;

for (int i = 0; i < randomN; ++i)
    grades.push_back(rand() % 91 + 10);
```

Comment: I didn't downvote, but I wonder if he'll lose points for using `vector`?

Comment: Just guessing here, but the STL probably hasn't been covered yet in class, so the only way to know about it, would be to have gotten help from an experienced programmer. If asked, could he (the OP) justify why a vector is better than a standard C array? I don't disagree with your answer, just recalling the days when I was a student...

Comment: @Alan: This is not a homework help site. It's a question and answer site aimed at building up a large archive of helpful answers. Wrong answers, even if they might be what the OP really wants, make the site less valuable. If he wants help specific to his classroom circumstances, SO isn't the place to find it. (And see the FAQ. This site is for professional and enthusiast programmers looking for real world solutions to real world problems.)

Comment: Fair enough. You know the size of vector at allocation time, so initialize it to size `randomN`, and use `operator[]` to set the value, rather than `push_back` and avoid the reallocation cost.